# Change UIViewController to a UITableViewController?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I have a UITableView that i want to reload the data from. I know how to do that, but when calling it from [self.tableView reloadData], I get errors with my current UIViewController configuration like this:

```
@interface processViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
```

So my thought would be to change the UIViewController to a UITableViewController like this:

```
@interface processViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

// or this:

@interface processViewController : UITableViewController {
```

However, when trying to load the view i get this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "processView" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
```

When in interface builder, there is no `tableView` connection there (but there are delegate and dataSource).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Coulton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as though you need to set the identity (in other words the class) of the controller instance in Interface Builder to your custom subclass.

By the way, the `tableView` property of `UITableView` isn't ever exposed in IB, because it's essentially a synonym for the `view` property -- the two properties both refer to the same instance variable, `_view`. The `tableView` property simply is more strongly typed.

Just a side note: by convention, Objective-C class names should begin with a capital letter, i.e., `ProcessViewController`, not `processViewController`.

Comment: One other note: The `UITableView` class conforms to both the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols, so subclasses inherit the protocols.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So you are saying I should use option #2 in the interface? `@interface processViewController : UITableViewController {`. I tried that, and it still crashed with the same error. I have a view with a UITableView in it. What do identity do I need to set where? Thanks.

Comment: Go to Interface Builder and select the controller instance, and then go to the Identity tab in the Inspector and set the controller's identity to the name of your custom subclass of `UITableViewController`

Comment: Sorry - I am a big noob in this. Is this the 'processViewController part'. Also, where do i define it - in my View or file's owner?

Comment: Well, think about it -- a subclass of `UIView` can't also be a subclass of `UITableViewController`, so by process of elimination if your nib file only contains an instance of `UIView` and `File's Owner`, then...

Comment: Realized if that it expected my view to be a tableView - that's why it's crashing.