# Registering UITableViewController causes an exception in loadView method

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, xamarin

I'm experimenting with the `UITableViewController` class in Xamarin and found that when creating a new ViewController in Visual Studio and changing the base-class from `UIViewController` to `UITableViewController`, the application crashing upon start with the following exception.

[image: Unhandled Exception that is caused when loading a ViewController]

My ViewController basically looked like this:

```
[Register("MyViewController")]
public class MyViewController: UITableViewController
{
    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
    }
}
```

Once I removed the `[Register("MyViewController")]` annotation from the ViewController, it suddenly works. I've tried with and without deleting the xib and/or the designer file but the only way of fixing this exception was removing the annotation.

So my question is, what exactly this Register-annotation is doing, and what is causing an exception when the loadView method is called? Note that no exception is being thrown, if I inherit from `UIViewController`.

[These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607052/change-uiviewcontroller-to-a-uitableviewcontroller?rq=1) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917285/transition-subclass-of-uiviewcontroller-to-uitableviewcontroller) seems to be related, but they are talking about an Interface builder that I am not using, because I'm writing the UI in code with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Register` attribute tells the compiler how to tie a C# class to it's corresponding object in the XIB.  Even though you say you are creating your UI in code, it sounds like you are using a template that is creating both a class and a corresponding XIB file.  If you are not using XIB, you may just want to use the generic "Empty Class" template instead.

Comment: That sounds plausible, but why is working with a regular `UIViewController` when no XIB is available? And yes, I've used the ViewController template available in Xamarin/Visual Studio.